# Does $F_x \cong \mathcal O_x$ for every $x \in X$ implies that $F$ is an invertible sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic curve, and $F$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal O$ module such that for every point $x \in X$, the stalk $F_x$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal O_x$. Does it follow that $F$ is an invertible sheaf ?

Clearly, the converse holds. But I have no ideas for the first statement : I know that for any $x$, there is a germ $s_x$ which generate $F_x$ with trivial annihilator. So if I pick any $f \in F(U)$, with $U$ a neighborhood of $x$ I can take a neighborhood $V$ such that $f = \lambda.s$ where $\lambda \in \mathcal O(V)$. But the problem is, possibly $V$ depends on $f$, and I don't see how to pick a good $V$. 
Maybe this is wrong but I don't see how to build a counter-example.

(This is an exercise in the book of Rick Miranda, Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces.)

Comment: What is your definition of an invertible sheaf?

Comment: My definition is : a sheaf $F$ is invertible if there is a covering $\{ U_i\}$ such that $F_{| U_i} \cong \mathcal O_{| U_i}$.

Comment: Then I do not see your confusion. As you have said, given a point $x$, there is an open neighborhood $U_x$ such that $F_{|U_x}\cong \mathcal{O}_{|U_x}$. This gives an open covering doing what you want.

Comment: I don't understand also why I was confused, you are right. I think this is ok now.